# matplotlib geopandas plot chloropleth with set bins for colorscheme

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

## How do I set a consistent colorscheme for three `axes` in the same figure?

The following should be a wholly reproducible example to run the code and get the same figure I have posted below.

Get the shapefile data from the [Office for National Statistics](http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/8edafbe3276d4b56aec60991cbddda50_1?selectedAttribute=lad15cd). Run this in a terminal as a `bash` file / commands.

```sh
wget --output-document 'LA_authorities_boundaries.zip' 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8edafbe3276d4b56aec60991cbddda50_1.zip?outSR=%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A27700%2C%22wkid%22%3A27700%7D&session=850489311.1553456889'

mkdir LA_authorities_boundaries
cd LA_authorities_boundaries
unzip ../LA_authorities_boundaries.zip
```

The python code that reads the shapefile and creates a dummy `GeoDataFrame` for reproducing the behaviour.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file(
    'LA_authorities_boundaries/Local_Authority_Districts_December_2015_Full_Extent_Boundaries_in_Great_Britain.shp'
)

# 380 values
df = pd.DataFrame([])
df['AREA_CODE'] = gdf.lad15cd.values
df['central_pop'] = np.random.normal(30, 15, size=(len(gdf.lad15cd.values)))
df['low_pop'] = np.random.normal(10, 15, size=(len(gdf.lad15cd.values)))
df['high_pop'] = np.random.normal(50, 15, size=(len(gdf.lad15cd.values)))
```

Join the shapefile from ONS and create a `geopandas.GeoDataFrame`

```py
def join_df_to_shp(pd_df, gpd_gdf):
    """"""
    df_ = pd.merge(pd_df, gpd_gdf[['lad15cd','geometry']], left_on='AREA_CODE', right_on='lad15cd', how='left')

    # DROP the NI counties
    df_ = df_.dropna(subset=['geometry'])

    # convert back to a geopandas object (for ease of plotting etc.)
    crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
    gdf_ = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df_, crs=crs, geometry='geometry')
    # remove the extra area_code column joined from gdf
    gdf_.drop('lad15cd',axis=1, inplace=True)

    return gdf_

pop_gdf = join_df_to_shp(df, gdf)
```

Make the plots

```py
fig,(ax1,ax2,ax3,) = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(15,6))

pop_gdf.plot(
    column='low_pop', ax=ax1, legend=True,  scheme='quantiles', cmap='OrRd',
)
pop_gdf.plot(
    column='central_pop', ax=ax2, legend=True, scheme='quantiles', cmap='OrRd',
)
pop_gdf.plot(
    column='high_pop', ax=ax3, legend=True,  scheme='quantiles', cmap='OrRd',
)
for ax in (ax1,ax2,ax3,):
    ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

## I want all three `ax` objects to share the same bins (preferable the `central_pop` scenario `quantiles`) so that the legend is consistent for the whole figure. The `quantiles` from ONE scenario (central) would become the `levels` for all

This way I should see darker colors (more red) in the far right `ax` showing the `high_pop` scenario.

How can I set the colorscheme bins for the whole figure / each of the `ax` objects?

The simplest way I can see this working is either
a) Provide a set of bins to the `geopandas.plot()` function
b) extract the colorscheme / bins from one `ax` and apply it to another.

Comment: In that case the notion "quantiles" makes no sense anymore, is that desired?

Comment: I want the quantiles from one of them to be used as the quantiles from all of them. Perhaps the quantiles from `central` being used in both `low` and `high`

Comment: Quantiles of one dataset can usually not be quantiles of another. I guess you just got the notion wrong, maybe use "levels" instead? Like "I want the quantiles from one of them to be used as levels for all"?

Comment: So one problem is that the geopandas plot API is a bit overloaded. Its `legend` argument has a different meaning, depending on whether you use a `scheme` or not. That makes custom binning hard when you want to get a legend (as opposed to a colorbar). It looks like this is solved in geopandas 0.5 though... let's see if I can get that running.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From geopandas 0.5 onwards you can use a custom scheme defined as `scheme="User_Defined"` and supply the binning via `classification_kwds`.

```
import geopandas as gpd
print(gpd.__version__)   ## 0.5
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')) 
gdf['quant']=np.random.rand(len(gdf))*100-20

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

gdf.plot(column='quant', cmap='RdBu', scheme="User_Defined", 
         legend=True, classification_kwds=dict(bins=[-10,20,30,50,70]),
         ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

So the remaining task is to get a list of bins from the quantiles of one of the columns. This should be easily done, e.g. via

```
import mapclassify
bins = mapclassify.Quantiles(gdf['quant'], k=5).bins
```

then setting `classification_kwds=dict(bins=bins)` in the above code.

[image]

Comment: How to remove those decimal numbers after the point in the legend?

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be (nigh) impossible as the `fmt` argument in the `legend_kwds` is not working. There is a solution mentioned here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281949 but it is amazingly involved for the simplicity of the ask.