# Plotting choropleth map with discrete colorbar/legend using Geopandas

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, geopandas, choropleth, legend-properties

I am trying to make a choropleth map using Geopandas. However I'm having trouble with the colourbar formatting, it seems to be very limited.

Here is the map I have:

[image: Map]

But I would like the colorbar(legend?) to be discrete breaks, or a colour key, I'm not really sure what to call it. Something like this:

[image: Discrete Color Key]

Is this even possible with Geopandas? I'm finding nothing in their documentation. Maybe something with [`legend_kwds`](http://geopandas.org/mapping.html#creating-a-legend)?

Here is my plotting code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (20, 12) )

ax.axis('off')

merged.plot(ax = ax, column = '2019-12', color = 'grey', label = 'No Data') #Plots 'No Data' layer
merged.dropna().plot(ax = ax, column = '2019-12', cmap = 'Reds', alpha = 1, legend = True) #Plots data layer

ax.legend()
```

In an ideal world, I'd also be able to manually set the numbers and limits of the intervals as well.

Comment: This is more like a suggestion, try to use a discrete colormap like Dark2 from this link here: https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: @DanielLima that's closer to what I want but not quite. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: You can create a custom color map with discrete colors (no gradient) and label all the different colors how you have it in the second image, but the color bar wouldn't appear broken - it would look like the color bar in the first image except with discrete colors. Would that suffice?

Comment: Maybe check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56695238/4124317) and possibly update the question with any remaining problem.

Comment: That answered most of my question -- Still would like to know some more capabilities like maybe defining equal-interval classes or making `< 3, 3-6, > 6' legends for instance but this is good enough for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56695238/8056865) helped a lot. I was able to use `classification_kwds` and define my own bins using using the `User_Defined` `scheme` argument when calling `gpd.plot()`. Although I would like more functionality, this is good enough for now.